# WebApi returns Http error 500, probably a routing issue

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api-routing

I have the following Web Api class:

```
public class BizAuthController : ApiController
{
    [HttpPost]
    public __BizAuthModel Register([FromBody] __BizAuthModel authInfo)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
          //... do whatever
        }
        throw new HttpResponseException(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public __BizAuthModel Login([FromBody] __BizAuthModel authInfo)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
          //... do whatever
        }
        throw new HttpResponseException(HttpStatusCode.Forbidden);
    }

}
```

This is my WebApiConfig (standard, I didn't touch it):

```
public static class WebApiConfig
{
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        // Web API configuration and services

        // Web API routes
        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
}
```

Now, if I delete the "Login" method the "Register" can be called and works fine. If I keep the "Login" method then calling the "Register" returns Http Error 500.
Why? and how can I fix this?

Comment: framework does not know which action to use on POST. Those two action match the default `routeTemplate`. How do you intend on calling the action?. you may need to up date the convention-based route to `api/{controller}/{action}/{id}` and call the actions by name rather than by only HttpMethod. ie: `POST api/BizAuth/Register` and `POST api/BizAuth/Login`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

framework does not know which action to use on POST. Those two action match the default `routeTemplate`.

Update the convention-based route to `api/{controller}/{action}/{id}` and call the actions by name rather than by only HttpMethod. ie: `POST api/BizAuth/Register` and `POST api/BizAuth/Login`

```
public static class WebApiConfig
{
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        // Web API configuration and services

        // Web API routes
        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );

    }
}
```

Comment: Either I don't understand REST or I don't understand Web API. Is the idea of the Web API is that every controller will be compound of only one POST action and one GET action etc? or does the REST suggest this? I really don't know. However, I always call with the action name, I thought that the default route mechanism of the Web API works the same way as the regular Web controllers. Anyway, I changes it as suggested here and it suites my needs. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

In **ASP.NET Web API 2** you may also try adding **`[Route]`** filters directely to the `Register` action method of the api for distinguish it from the `Login`, that should be default get operation, and leave the `WebApiConfig.Register` route config method as is:

```
public class BizAuthController : ApiController
{
    [HttpPost]
    [Route("Register")]
    public __BizAuthModel Register([FromBody] __BizAuthModel authInfo)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
          //... do whatever
        }
        throw new HttpResponseException(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public __BizAuthModel Login([FromBody] __BizAuthModel authInfo)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
          //... do whatever
        }
        throw new HttpResponseException(HttpStatusCode.Forbidden);
    }
}
```